# Recurence Problem. - Solve either by substitution or Expansion

Tags: asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

> Function T(n) is defined by the following recurrence relation:
>
> $$ T(n)=2T(\lfloor\sqrt{ n}\rfloor)+\log(n) $$
>
> $$ T(0)=1 $$

How would I Solve by substitution and/or Expansion?

**Note: Correct answer:** $\Theta(\log(n) \times \log (\log(n))) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get an upper bound, you can use similar reasoning to get the lower bound. First establish that $T(1)=0$ by algebraic manipulation, then note that $T(n)$ is monotonically increasing for $n\ge 1$. Thus we can get that for all $n$ greater then or equal to one we have: $T(\lfloor{n}\rfloor)\leq T(n)$ which gives us:

$$T(\lfloor{n}\rfloor)\leq 2T(\lfloor{n^{1/2}}\rfloor)+\ln(n)$$
$$\text{Now subtracting }2T(\lfloor{n^{1/2}}\rfloor) \text{ from both sides of the inequality:}$$
$$T(\lfloor{n}\rfloor)-2T(\lfloor{n^{1/2}}\rfloor)\leq\ln(n)$$
$$\text{ Multiplying both sides by }2^{k-1} \text{ gives: }$$
$$2^{k-1}T(\lfloor{n}\rfloor)-2^kT(\lfloor{n^{1/2}}\rfloor)=2^{k-1}\ln(n)$$
$$\text{ Setting }n=m^{1/2^{k-1}} \text{ gives: }$$
$$2^{k-1}T(\lfloor{m^{1/2^{k-1}}}\rfloor)-2^{k}T(\lfloor{m^{1/2^{k}}}\rfloor)=\ln(m)$$
$$\text{Summing from } k=1 \text{ to an integer } k=L \text{ gives us a telescoping series which results in:}$$
$$T(\lfloor{m}\rfloor)-2T(\lfloor{m^{1/2}}\rfloor)+2T(\lfloor{m^{1/2}}\rfloor)-4T(\lfloor{m^{1/4}}\rfloor)+...=L\ln(m)$$
$$\text{ Then canceling like terms gives:}$$
$$T(\lfloor{m}\rfloor)-2^{L}T(\lfloor{m^{1/2^L}}\rfloor)\leq L\ln(m)$$ 
$$\text{Now set } L=\lceil{\log_2(\log_2(m))}\rceil+1 \text{ and note that: } m^{1/2^{L}}\leq m^{1/2^{\log_2(\log_2(m))+1}}<m^{1/2^{\log_2(\log_2(m)}}=2$$
$$\text{ Implying } \lfloor{m^{1/2^{L}}}\rfloor=1 \text{ which gives us that:}$$
$$T(\lfloor{m}\rfloor)-2^{L}T(\lfloor{m^{1/2^L}}\rfloor)\leq 
(\lceil{\log_2(\log_2(m))}\rceil+1)\ln(m)$$
$$\text{ And so we have:}$$
$$T(\lfloor{m}\rfloor)\leq 
(\lceil{\log_2(\log_2(m))}\rceil+1)\ln(m)$$
$$\text{Now letting } m=r+1 \text{ gives us that: }$$
$$T(r)\leq T(\lfloor{r}\rfloor+1)\leq 
(\lceil{\log_2(\log_2(r+1))}\rceil+1)\ln(r+1)$$
$$\text{ Thus we get:}$$
$$T(r)=O(\log(r)\times \log(\log(r))$$